# How to write Classes in Javascript and Code management?

Tags: javascript, performance, version-control, standards

If I am not wrong then there is no such thing as `'Class'` in javascript instead everything is object.

But I happen to find a code/script which actually has a class.

I want to know how (Code example given below)

1) Is this type of code writing helpful in managing the code and function? (Yeah, I think everything is within global Sidebar object so its good, namespaced, no conflict. Your opinion?)

2) How do you call any function written within this type of class?

3) Is there actually any performance improvement with such style? Can someone post a better working example?
Script has been taken from http://jsfiddle.net/js/Sidebar.js

// Notice reportAbuse function .... How to call functions within function? Are they publicly accessible

```
var Sidebar = new Class({ 
  Implements: [Options, Events],
  parameter: "Sidebar",
  options: {
      DOM: '',
      toggleSidebar: 'toggleSidebar'
  },

  initialize: function(options) {
      this.setOptions(options);
      // Some more code
  },

  toElement: function() {
      return this.element;
  },

  hide: function() {
      this.element.hide();
      this.contentMargin = $('content').getStyle('marginLeft');
      $('content').setStyle('marginLeft', 13);
      this.hidden = true;
      Layout.resize();
  },

  show: function() {
      $('content').setStyle('marginLeft', this.contentMargin);
      this.element.show();
      this.hidden = false;
      Layout.resize();
  },

  reportAbuse: {

      setup: function() {
          this.element = {
              textarea: document.id('abuse-text'),
              submit: document.id('send-abuse')
          };

          if (this.element.textarea && this.element.submit) {
              this.element.submit.addEvents({
                  click: this.validate.bind(this)
              });
          }
      },  

      validate: function(event) {
          event.stop();

          if (this.element.textarea.get('value').trim() !== '') {
              this.send();
          } else {
              this.element.textarea.highlight();
          }
      }
      // Few more functions within reportAbuse function
  }
});
```

Comment: javascript dont have classes.Period.

Comment: classes??? JS only deals with objects, no? maybe its a make-believe class

Comment: As I mentioned above I am aware of the Objects concept in JS but I am interested to know more about the above code the snippet has been taken from a reputed site jsfiddle.net. Question edited. So if they are using such convention then what does this means? Is there a way I can follow the same and improve something?

Comment: [http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)

Answer (score 0):

The code above is likely to be used in combination with the library prototypejs

@see http://prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance.html

This is useful to organize your code and to create such structures/objects without much trouble

With the code above, creating a new Sidebar object is as simple as

```
var sidebar1 = new Sidebar();
```

and then call any function defined in it like this:

> sidebar1.show();